# jQuery subtotal of HTML column on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the following structure:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Price">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="sum_amount" placeholder="Total amount">    

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="sum_total" placeholder="Grand total">      

<table class="table" id="tab1">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Amount</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>

                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="tableSell">
                            <tr>
                                <td>625</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>625</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>638</td>
                                <td>2.5</td>
                                <td>1595</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>640</td>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>2560</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I need to calculate the subtotals of 'Amount' and 'Total' columns based on the clicked row.
Example:
If the second row is clicked: 'Total amount' = 3.5, 'Grand total' = 2220

I've been able to achive copying of the price to the first field

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tab1 tr").click(function(){
    $("#price").val($(this).find(':first-child').text());
  });
});
```

but I have no idea how to develop the subtotals.

The workspace: http://jsfiddle.net/Tge9A/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**: Fixed to `parseFloat()` and added JSFiddle.

Try initializing your totals to the current ones in the row. Then loop back to all the previous rows and add those to the totals like so (this would go in your `.click()` function):

```
var totalAmount = parseFloat($(this).children('td').eq(1).text());
var grandTotal = parseFloat($(this).children('td').eq(2).text());
$(this).prevAll('tr').each(function() {
    totalAmount += parseFloat($(this).children('td').eq(1).text());
    grandTotal += parseFloat($(this).children('td').eq(2).text());
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RVwF/1/)

You might also want to specify your selector for your click event to be more like:

```
$('#tab1 > tbody > tr')
```

This will prevent parse errors since the header row in your `thead` section won't be selected with this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tab1 tr").click(function(){
      var amount = parseFloat($(this).find(':eq(1)').text());
      var price = $(this).find(':first-child').text();
      var total = 0;

      //add one to amount and get this rows total
      amount += 1;
      total = amount * price;

      var grandTotal = 0;
      var sum_amount = 0;  

 //update the row 
 $(this).find(':eq(1)').text(amount);
 $(this).find(':eq(2)').text(total); 

  var count = 0;

  //now loop through the rows and get the totals - the count is to ignore the first row as it is table headings
  $.each($('table tr'), function( i, val ) {

      if (count > 0){
          sum_amount += parseFloat($(val).find(':eq(1)').text());
          grandTotal += parseFloat($(val).find(':eq(2)').text());
      }

      count ++;
```

});

```
  $('#sum_amount').val(sum_amount);
  $('#sum_total').val(grandTotal);
```

});
});

http://jsfiddle.net/Tge9A/2/

Comment: I don't think they want it to recursively add like that, but again, I could be wrong. The question wasn't very clear in the first place.

Comment: agreed not clear - hopefully one of us will have given the answer they were looking for :-P

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't be recursively added, sorry if the question was unclear.

Comment: No problem - should have guessed by the 2220 as 3.5 row is 2233 :-P however there should be some useful stuff in there for you I hope. Good luck

Comment: Thank you, of course it is useful, and I marked it as such :)